# Cannot get SCP to work even though SSH works

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, scp

I have a remote VPS that I can succesfully connect to via SSH, using my SSH key. I disabled password authentication in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

I have not been able to get scp to work despite reviewing several other threads on similar topics. Here is exactly what I am doing and the result (coincidentally same username on both local and remote):

`scp -vvv -i /home/xixor/.ssh/id_rsa /home/xixor/testfile1 xixor@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/home/xixor/temp`

Result:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, user xixor, command scp -v -t /home/xixor/temp
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xxx.xx.xxx is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/xixor/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/xixor/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

scp is installed on the remote server and work just copying things to/from locations on that server. Is there a debug log I can find somewhere on the server that would give any more information on what is happening? (i.e. info beyond the output above from my local machine when executing the command with -vvv flag)

Comment: That "Connection timed out" error indicates a network connectivity problem (or maybe incorrect port or something). This sort of problem should affect ssh in the same way, so I'd investigate what's different there. Try connecting with `ssh -vvv` and see if the "debug1: Connecting to ..." message matches.

Comment: Also check `type ssh` and/or `which ssh` (depending on your shell) to make sure the _program file_ you run when you directly give the command `ssh` is the same program file `scp` runs